# Trigger update some table without updating main table

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

Because of my front-end app I cannot use PostgreSQL views. So I have a dummy table where I temporarily insert records just to trigger inserts on three more tables. That dummy record is then deleted.

Tables are `company`, `phone`, `company_phone` and `dummy_company` :)

Inserts are fine, but in order to update that data across three tables I thought to make a trigger on update of the dummy table and update the real tables without touching the dummy table (since it is empty).

Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_company() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
  BEGIN
    UPDATE phone SET number = NEW.number
      WHERE id = NEW.phone_id;
    UPDATE company SET name = NEW.name
      WHERE id = NEW.id;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_company BEFORE UPDATE ON dummy_company
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_company();
```

So I want an update trigger on a empty table that updates other tables. Is that possible?

Comment: You cannot update a non-existing row, the trigger won't ever fire.

Comment: Even if set to fire BEFORE? So it's not possible to have something like INSTEAD OF but for tables?

Comment: Unfortunately not. A trigger is fired before update but there are no updates on an empty table.

Comment: Why exactly can't you use a view? What differences between a table and a view are the problem? A view is just a table with an `INSTEAD OF SELECT` rule called `_RETURN`.

Comment: Because my API, `hasura`, doesn't support updating on a view. What I am really trying to do is split tables into many smaller ones in order to have better design but it is giving me hard time to handle all CRUDs that way. Eg. I have tables person(name, birthday...) and student(grades, enrolled_date...).